# bash cannot find the command `debug-safari` on macOS Catalina

Tags: xcode, safari, webkit, html5-audio, web-audio-api

I'm trying to debug an issue with HTML5 WebAudio API, provided in Safari via WebKit. I came across this `debug-safari` command and tried to run it but bash can't find it.

The issue is related to the creation of `AudioNode`/`ScriptProcessorNode` via `createScriptProcessor()`. When I try to log the properties of the object returned by `createScriptProcessor()`, I see `[Native Code]` written in console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `debug-safari` command is provided by [WebKit](https://webkit.org/).

Do this:

1. Get the WebKit repo: `svn checkout https://svn.webkit.org/repository/webkit/trunk WebKit`
2. Go to the Scripts folder: `cd Webkit/Tools/Scripts` (Alternatively, add the Scripts folder to your Path: `[Path-To-Downloaded-WebKit-Repo]/Tools/Scripts` and run without the `./` prefix)
3. Run the update script: `./update-webkit`
4. Build the framework in debug mode: `./build-webkit --debug`
5. Now, run: `./debug-safari`

**Note:** It is assumed that you have [Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/) and [Xcode Command Line Tools](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/resources/) installed.